# how to Delete the rows those are not present in Table 1

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys hi need your help i am tried alot and now i am tired find no way out.

I have two tables & i did inner join want to remove those rows which foreign id is not present in table 2, below i have mentioned by structure..

**Table 1**

```
     Column A(Foreign)     Column B  

     record A              Some thing
     record B              Some thing
     record c              Some thing
```

**Table 2**

```
     Column A(Foreign)     Column B  

     record A              Some thing
     record B              Some thing
```

*Now actually i want to remove record C which is not in the table 2..is there any way out???*

Comment: Please post your best effort even if it didn't produce the right result.  At least we will know what we **don't** need to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `Table 1` t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM `Table 2` t2
    WHERE t2.`Column A(Foreign)` = t1.`Column A(Foreign)`
)
```

Terrible table and column names, by the way

Demo here - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c2d8/1

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
DELETE VM.* FROM `Table1` AS VM
LEFT JOIN `Table2` AS VL
ON VL.`Column A(Foreign)` = VM.`Column A(Foreign)d`
WHERE VL.`Column A(Foreign)` IS NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, working.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5f02/1

```
create table t1 (
  a varchar(16),
  b varchar(16)
);

create table t2 (
  a varchar(16),
  b varchar(16)
);

insert into t1 values
('record A', 'Some thing'),
('record B', 'Some thing'),
('record c', 'Some thing');

insert into t2 values
('record A', 'Some thing'),
('record B', 'Some thing');

delete t1
FROM  t1 left outer join t2 
ON t1.a = t2.a
where t2.a is null
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the result OP wants?

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks for pointing out please now check I've corrected the code.